# Recommended sizes for Media Queries, to cover tablets phones laptops and desktops

Tags: css, size, media-queries

What are the best Media Query sizes to use to be sure you've targeted tablets, phones, laptops and desktops as best you can?

For example: The iPhone and Droid have a screen size of 320X480, therefore it would be good to make sure the design looks good at those sizes, since a lot of phones out there are this size. What other sizes would it be good to target? I'm not looking JUST for iphone/ipad sizes, but in general. Especially since there's more Android devices out there now than iOS devices, and Android devices tend to be of so many different sizes.

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
/* would target landscape for the droid, iphone 3, etc. */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
/* would target portrait for the droid, iphone 3, etc. */
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look at mine, http://dev.bowdenweb.com/a/css/media-queries-boilerplate.css  but i took most of them from hard boiled media queries, http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/hardboiled_css3_media_queries

Comment: first css file does not exist as of writing this.

Comment: @Narretz are you sure? Works for me...

Comment: @TryingToImprove i lost my server in early 2012. i've tried to duplicate it as much as possible, but he probably saw it when it was down. actually i think his comment was my clue that the document was missing

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.binvisions.com/articles/tablet-smartphone-resolutions-screen-size-list/) is a great link to screen sizes.

Personally, since the iPad is by FAR the most popular tablet device, design the medium screen size (1024x768) to that specification (iPad 2 size) - any larger than that and you're running in to desktop size.

For Smart Phone size I would go with 960x640, although that will probably increase for iphone and android within the next year if not sooner.